# Order of channel Handlers in Netty

Tags: netty

I'm trying to learn netty channel handlers and I'm stumbling on this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/netty).

In the File `NettyServer.java`, the author mentioned about registering the channel handlers to channel pipeline.

```
    ch.pipeline().addLast(
    new RequestDecoder(), 
    new ResponseDataEncoder(), 
    new ProcessingHandler());
```

This order is bit confusing me. I would've registered the order as below since

1. request is decoded
2. decoded request is processed and response is generated
3. response is decoded is the correct order.

   ```
   ch.pipeline().addLast(
   new RequestDecoder(),
   new ProcessingHandler(),
   new ResponseDataEncoder());
   ```

What is the reason behind the different ordering in Netty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is that inbound and outbound messages (and events) flow in different directions. Inbound data (so what you receive) will start from the head of the ChannelPipeline while messages that you write will start from the end. So the order of the called handlers is different.

Check the ChannelPipeline javadocs which also has some sort of diagram to make it more clear:

http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html